# Is it possible to set interrupt priorities to software interrupts in ARM?

Tags: arm, interrupts

Is it possible to for example give SWI 0x1 a priority of 15 and SWI 0x2 a priority of 16? If yes, is this useful? I understand why giving hardware interrupts a different priority is useful, but is it also useful for software interrupts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The priority of a software interrupt with respect to another software interrupt is meaningless: a software interrupt is an instruction, hence it is executed when it is encountered in the instruction stream. The subsequent instructions might depend on its result, so suspending the SWI to a later moment is not a good idea.

A hardware interrupt is something that occurs asynhronous with the instruction stream, hence it can be postponed when whatever the current instruction stream is doing is more time-ciritcal (or uses a non-shareable resource).

Comment: I would argue that it *has* meaning, just not from a hardware perspective. Software priority is established by the scheduler, so to implement software interrupt priority you would need some basic threading element or at least a software scheduler for software priority to have meaning

Comment: What you propose gives meaning (implements) multithreading/processing/fibring, with different priorities for each thread. That has nothing to do with SWI instructions, which are essentially subroutine calls that can cross a security boundary (change the protection level).